# Asp.Net concat tables so they order by correctly C# LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, linq

I am making a view that shows a table order by a kind of column:

VIEW:

```
@*<a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { filtro = "plantacao comeca", ordem
= "desc"})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { filtro = "plantacao comeca", ordem = "asc"})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></a>*@
```

CONTROLLER:

```
case "plantacao comeca":
    var january = artigo.Where(a => a.plantacaoComeca == "January");
    var february = artigo.Where(a => a.plantacaoComeca == "February");

    // and so on and so one
    // I whant to contact this tables in order where !!!
    break;
```

So I would like to know how to concact this tables or to order them with diferent strings  or numbers or what so ever.....

Comment: Is it possible to change your model's `plantacaoComeca` to an `int` and use the month number, instead? This would be much easier to `GroupBy()` and `OrderBy()`. Then you could just convert the `int` into a month string to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string representation of the Month to a `DateTime` and then `OrderBy` it. Finally, because the new `SortValue` isn't relevant for the output I've added a `select`

```
var sortedByMonths = artigo
    .Select(item => new { Item = item, SortValue = DateTime.ParseExact(item.plantacaoComeca , "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
    .OrderBy(item => item.SortValue)
    .Select(item => item.Item)
    .ToList();
```

You can also use `Where` and `Concat` (but I think it is less nice):

```
var january = artigo.Where(a => a.plantacaoComeca == "January");
var february = artigo.Where(a => a.plantacaoComeca == "February");

january.Concat(february).Concat(....)
```

Comment: @user2278362 - Did it help you solve the issue? Is this question still unsolved?

Comment: Good. Glad to hear :)

Comment: @user2278362 - please consider upvoting and marking as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem with combining the `Where` into one query?

```
var januaryFebruary = artigo.Where(
    a => a.plantacaoComeca == "January" 
      || a.plantacaoComeca == "February");
```